# laravel 5.3 action with parameter doesn't work

Tags: laravel-5.3

I have problem with route action have parameters.
this is my Web route :

```
Route::get('/services/[id]/[title]', 'SiteController@services');
```

and this is my blade link :

```
<a href="{{action('SiteController@services',['id'=>'4','title'=>'4'])}}" class="text-blue transition-5 padding-top-30 display-block"> More </a>
```

But when i click on this link i have this url :

```
http://localhost:8000/services/%5Bid%5D/%5Btitle%5D?id=4&title=4
```

and in wamp i cant see my pages , i have db not found error. but in localhost800 not problem :| help me please thansk all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your route variables should be with {} not []. So it should look like this;

```
Route::get('/services/{id}/{title}', 'SiteController@services');
```

Then check if you can actually get to that route by manually going to "/services/4/4".

Comment: Omg :| Thank You Men .. Was My Terrible Mistake xD

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
<a href="/services/4/4" class="text-blue transition-5 padding-top-30 display-block"> More </a>
```

Comment: @D Coder I know , but why i cant do this with action? its my htacess problem?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.